# Identify this bridal dress torso

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify this brides dress torso:

[image]

I've searched on Bricklink for dress, white dress, and bridesmaid, but couldn't find it. I also have 1 in my collection but would like to buy more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Keyword for this torso on Bricklink is "flower".

[Torso Female Wrapped Dress with Pink Flower Pattern / Yellow Arms / Yellow Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1247c01)

It was used just for Fairy from [Series 8](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=746.784) of Collectable Minifigures:

[image]